# imap_open dies when being called

Tags: php, imap

I've got the following code:

> print "foo"; 
>   imap_open("{localhost:143/imap/notls}", "myname", "mypass"); 
>   print "bar";

The script dies. I get zero responds, nothing from apache, no "foo" or "bar", nothing.

I can however connect to the imap server (nc localhost ...), I can also put the script on another server and connect to the same imap server. So, I think there's something wrong with the php on this server. But I can't figure out what I'm missing, forgetting or didn't install.
phpinfo() tells me php is configured --with-imap and --with-imap-ssl. The OS is CentOS, btw.

Comment: is imap enabled in the php.ini? phpinfo() would shed some light

Comment: Small update.. when I run it in cli, it works, but when run from apache, it segfaults..

Comment: Ok, found the problem.  libc_client was compiled against a header file with FD_SETSIZE set low. With this server being a shared hosting server, it had crashed because there were too many open file descriptors... Recompile of libc_client did the trick.

Comment: Is there any way to increase the fd_setsize live? I'm having similar issues and do not have control of php (shared hosting)

Comment: Can you answer your question below so that this question doesn't hang out in the 'unanswered' que?

Comment: or close it if you don't want to add the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, sorry... So the answer is this: :)

Ok, found the problem. libc_client was compiled against a header file with FD_SETSIZE set low. With this server being a shared hosting server, it had crashed because there were too many open file descriptors... Recompile of libc_client did the trick